# Is it possible to zoom into a base layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, mapping, openlayers, wms

I have an OpenLayers map, which uses [OpenSpace](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/web-services/os-openspace/api/index.html) as a base layer, and is overlayed with a WMS layer supplied by my system. The issue I have is that the detail from my WMS layer is very fine grained and the default levels of zoom that OpenLayers has isn't close enough to allow for distinct viewing of the features (for background its mapping drains on a street which are often opposite each other).

The client has no real interest in preserving the base layer quality, and would be happy to zoom in closer at the cost of loss of quality of the base layer. I cannot seem to achieve this in open layers. Does anyone have any knowledge of how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at OpenLayers’s ClientZoom functionnality: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/clientzoom.html

Comment: This seems to somewhat work, but openlayers seems to still be requesting the tiles from the tile server, even though the server resolutions are set. This is resulting in a 404 on the tiles

Comment: If you check in firebug, you’ll see it isn’t the case in the example. Maybe you can share some code of yours which reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe the issue is that serverResolutions is a property of XYZ not WMS, and so isn't used in the standard WMS layer.

Comment: Oh yeah, I read too quickly, you’re right. Not sure how you could achieve this with WMS…

Comment: In fact you didnt say your base layer was WMS. Couldn’t you switch it to a WMTS layer?